# How to bind "\C-;" in ~/.inputrc?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, readline, rxvt

I use Meta-ijkl as arrows in Emacs, and `M-;` as a backspace, so I want to make the keys in bash represent the same style. Moving and deleting works well, but for some reason I cannot bind `unix-line-discard` to `C-;` that would erase the whole line from the cursor to the beginning into the kill buffer. Since default emacs keys for copy, kill and yank are `C-j`, `C-k` and `C-y`, another C- combination fits there quite well. And `\e:` (Meta-Shift-;) is already bound to `backward-kill-word`. `C-u` that does `unix-line-discard` by default, works fine, but it’s inconvenient to press. If I rebind this function to, say, `\C-g`, it works fine, too.

In the `~/.inputrc` I have

```
"\C-;": unix-line-discard
```

I’ve also tried

```
"\C-\;": unix-line-discard
"\C-\x3b": unix-line-discard
```

with no effect. `C-v C-;` in the shell doesn’t print anything except for the usual semicolon, and `\C-;` with all its variants only prints it, too, and nothing more.

I work in Urxvt.

Comment: Your terminal is probably only able to generate control codes of the chars with code values 0x40 to 0x5f, which doesnt include `;`.

Comment: Not possible with configuring readline alone. Which terminal are you using? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9941824/1213041

Comment: @cdosborn urxvt.

Comment: Try the suggestion of this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26741764/1213041).

Comment: @cdosborn no luck with `\C-\x1b` or `\C-[1;2P`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agreeing with the comment by @meuh, terminals don't generate a distinct code for <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> (normally).

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922497/how-can-i-set-tmux-hotkey-as-ctrl-that-is-ctrlcomma/26741764#26741764) suggested by @tijagi is for `xterm` and does not apply to `urxvt`.  Using the manual page for `urxvt` shows that you can start here:

```
   keysym.sym: string
       Compile frills: Associate string with keysym sym. The intervening
       resource name keysym. cannot be omitted.
```

and use a setting like one of these:

```
*keysym.Control-semicolon: mybinding
URxvt.keysym.Control-semicolon: mybinding
```

using the class name as necessary to override existing resources, and
where *mybinding* is whatever you care to have `urxvt` send when you type <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> (but read the manual page to get the syntax right).  @meuh suggests using `\025` (`^U`) since that is normally bound to `unix-line-discard`.

Further reading:

- [rxvt-unicode (ouR XVT, unicode) - (a VT102 emulator for the X window system)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/urxvt)

Comment: The actual line to put in your resources (eg .Xdefaults) is `URxvt.keysym.Control-semicolon: \025` or you can just try it out with the command `urxvt -xrm 'URxvt.keysym.Control-semicolon: \025'`  The `025` is the octal code for `Control-U` which is the default binding for bash's `unix-line-discard`.